# Node: Mustache templates on both server and client

Tags: node.js, mustache

I would like to use mustache templates with node.js/express/hogan.
But I would also like to use mustache templates on the client with ember.js

How is this problem normally solved?
Should I use different template engines on server/client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the delimiter in Hogan:
app.locals.delimiters = '[[ ]]';

This works fine.